# log file not generated in Log4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, spring-tool-suite

I am tried to implements log4j. I have created a sample java program with log4j.

Below is my log4j.properties:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, FILE
log = /ciheul/Projects/ais-projects/backend/ais/backend/src/resources

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I am getting the output in the console screen.But the log file is not getting generated. what must i do to generate logging file, thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible options, your application does not have rights to write to the root of Tomcat folder, you can change the folder or give your application permissions to create files